# calculating storage based upon on eps?

Tags: multiplicative-function

If an organization collects an average of $20,000$ EPS
over eight hours of an ongoing incident, that will require sorting and analysis of
$576,000,000$ data records. Using a $300$ byte average size, that amounts to $172.8$
gigabytes of data.

[link](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/analysts_program/eventMgt_Feb09.pdf)

I'm not clear how this $172.8$ was calculated. I know `576,000,000` was taken by multiplying 8 hours into seconds. Should i divide the $300$ byte average size? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$576000000\cdot300=172800000000=172.8\cdot10^9\;.$$

Comment: but thats bytes not GB? which is 160.933 GB. not 172.8

Comment: A [gigabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) is usually defined as $10^9$ bytes, though an alternative definition as $2^{30}$ bytes is also in use.

Comment: if i do a google convert using convert 172800000000 to GB it gives me 160.

Comment: If your concern is with different definitions of a gigabyte, you should ask about that, and this wouldn't be the appropriate forum. Here you asked about how the number 172.8 was calculated, and I answered that question.

Comment: oh i got it google is using 2^30 not 10^9. I got it:) thanks:)